# Inconsistent object placement inside CardView with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

EDIT:

ADDITIONAL DETAILS: Strangely enough, it only gets buggy if there are only <=3 elements. More than that, because every element can be scrolled away, then the layout will "fix" itself upon reshowing.

ADDITIONAL DETAILS: Link to the demo video that showing the problem.

[Youtube Video - https://youtu.be/zlwi_Bz-HQo](https://youtu.be/zlwi_Bz-HQo)

---

So below screenshot, was taken from the same run from an android studio.

In the screenshot, I have 2 exact same card view (with dummy data straight from the .xml, so, I assign no data from java file).

[image]
**The problem**

1. If you guys look at the bottom right of each `CardView`, there's a
   text view called "read more".

   Weirdly enough, even if they're identical, it's placed differently.
   Btw, it's actually 3 identical cards. On the first run, the top "read
   more" also incorrectly placed, but it auto-corrected itself when I
   completely scroll it down and back to the top.
2. The second problem is the 5x4 dots on the top of the card. It's differently placed from what it's seen from the editor.

[image]

(The placement is accurate on editor)

**Any idea how to handle this irregularity? Thanks.**

Btw, I'm not sure if you guys need the code, but just in case, here it is on Pastebin (to shorten the post length).

- [visit_note_timeline.xml](http://pastebin.com/zLpPtvtx) (the cardview)
- [VisitNoteAdapter.java](http://pastebin.com/SydRPZRm) (In case you're wondering, "visit note" is just a dummy empty class)
- [MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/EjSFVY2N)
- [ratings_previews.xml](http://pastebin.com/zSiR5Ase) (the 5x4 white dots on top right of the card, under more button)
- [activity_main.xml](http://pastebin.com/LjCqP3ab)
- [content_main.xml](http://pastebin.com/885Mqdpi)

Comment: your youtube video isn't working, it gets stuck. Please upload a new video for the same.

Comment: @VipulAsri done. please check it out again.

Comment: If you delete the XML elements other than the "read more", there is still happened the same problem?

Comment: @nshmura yeah. basically every element that has `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and has margin right > 0 is considered doesn't have any right margin before get scrolled down. The top right element (more button) also buggy.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem (there is many unknown theme, drawable).
Could you make minimum layout file to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @nshmura yes. i'll make it when I come back home

Comment: @nshmura btw, I remember there was a message when compiling to device: "Skipped <insert a number here> frames! The application maybe doing too much on its main thread".

Comment: @nshmura hi there. I have added the project github on the top of the OP. Please check it out.

Comment: @MosesAprico hi, thank you. I'll chck it.

Comment: @MosesAprico Saddly enough, I can't build your project, since there are not exists following resources:
`@drawable/profile_img`, 
`@layout/visit_note_timeline`, 
`@layout/visitnote_ratings`

Comment: @nshmura wait a minute. Those files suddenly vanished from my computer as well.. :/

Comment: @nshmura fixed it. I also added the "read more" button again. Please check it out

Comment: Thanks. I could reproduce this issue and add answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use match_parent for RecyclerView.

Fix like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_timeline"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

If parent view's width is `wrap_content`, parent view's width can not be determined until child view's width is determed.
I don't know the result of setting `layout_width="wrap_content"` for parent view and `layout_width="match_parent"` for child view.
I guess the result may be wrong layout.
In your layout, the same situation is happend.
`RecyclerView` has `layout_width="wrap_content"` and `CardView` has `layout_width="match_parent"`.

Comment: wow it works! thanks. btw can you some explanation why this thing happens? I'd like to learn android behaviors. Thank you!